# How to protect the cell/range at the same time as appendrow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Im working on a website that stores data in a google spreadsheet and was wondering how I could use the appendrow() function and then protect that cell so no one can access it.

I'm new to google apps script and have been searching the internet for the last hour or so and can't find anything.

```js
sheet.appendRow([text]);
```

But after that I would like it to get the value of that cell that was just written on so I could write:

```js
var protection = the-row-just-written-on.protect()
```

I I am hoping for the result to be that no one can delete the text once it has been written on.

Comment: Use `rg = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1); rg.setValues([[text]])`. Then protect the `rg`

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you so much!